# How to set a css class to a day containing an event in jquery Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have a Fullcalendar implementation at: http://seattledesigndistrict.com/events/  Overall it works pretty well, I am still cleaning it up in the different browsers, but the thing works pretty well with my custom post type in WP.

The issue is that I would like to set add a css class to a day's `<td>` if there is an event inside of it.  The issue that I can see, so far, is that the events aren't even contained in the td, they are absolutely positioned inside it.

Any ideas how to get this done easily?  I am open to a small jQuery script as well... Just trying to hammer out a solution.

thanks

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the feature request:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=74